# How Read a Text File and Display it onto a TextBlock in Visual Studio (C#)

Tags: c#, windows, parsing, windows-phone-7

I am a newbie in Visual Studio (C#). I want to store a text read from a text file and display it on a TextBlock control, but just for a specified row. How can I do that?
I've try to search on the internet, and most of them just show the way to read and write.

I have one TextBlock (named 'FlashText'), and two Button (one for the 'Previous' button, another one is for the 'Next' button). What I want is, when I hit the 'Next' button, then the TextBlock showing a text read from a txt file on a specified row (for instance, the first row). And when I hit the 'Next' again, then the TextBlock should be show the second row text read from the file.

The purpose is to make a simple flash card. The code is here:

`

```
private void btnRight_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { 
  string filePath = @"D:\My Workspaces\Windows Phone 7 Solution\SimpleFlashCard\EnglishFlashCard.txt"; 
  int counter = 0;
  string line; 
  System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath); 
  while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) { 
    Console.WriteLine(line); 
    counter++; 
  } 
} 

file.Close(); 
FlashText.Text = Console.ReadLine();
```

`

Please help. Thanks a bunch.

---

**UPDATE:**

Recently the main code is:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private FlashCard _flashCard;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // This could go under somewhere like a load new flash card button or
        // menu option etc.
        try
        {
            _flashCard = new FlashCard(@"D:\My Workspaces\Windows Phone 7 Solution\FCard\MyDocuments\EnglishFlashCard.txt");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void btnLeft_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayPrevious();
    }

    private void btnRight_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayNext();
    }

    private void DisplayNext()
    {
        try
        {
            FlashText.Text = _flashCard.GetNextLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void DisplayPrevious()
    {
        try
        {
            FlashText.Text = _flashCard.GetPreviousLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is for the class '**FlashCard**':

```
public class FlashCard
{
    private readonly string _file;
    private readonly List<string> _lines;

    private int _currentLine;

    public FlashCard(string file)
    {
        _file = file;
        _currentLine = -1;

        // Ensure the list is initialized
        _lines = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            LoadCard();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); // This line got a message while running the solution
        }
    }

    private void LoadCard()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(_file))
        {
            // Throw a file not found exception
        }

        using (var reader = File.OpenText(_file))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                _lines.Add(line);
            }
        }
    }

    public string GetPreviousLine()
    {
        // Make sure we're not at the first line already
        if (_currentLine > 0)
        {
            _currentLine--;
        }

        return _lines[_currentLine]; //-- This line got an error
    }

    public string GetNextLine()
    {
        // Make sure we're not at the last line already
        if (_currentLine < _lines.Count - 1)
        {
            _currentLine++;
        }

        return _lines[_currentLine]; //-- This line got an error
    }
}
```

I've got at error message while running the solution: **Attempt to access the method failed: System.IO.File.Exists(System.String)**.

I've tried using breakpoint and while it's getting the LoadCard() method, it's directly thrown to the exception on the constructor. I've rechecked the txt path but it's true.

And I've also got an error message while hitting the 'Next' / 'Previous' button on '**return _lines[_currentLine];**' line said: **ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled** (It's occured on the GetPreviousLine() method if hitting the 'Previous' button and GetNextLine() method for the 'Next'.

Should you need more information I'm glad to provide it. :)

---

**UPDATE 2**

Here is the recent code:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private string path = @"D:\My Workspaces\Windows Phone 7 Solution\FCard\EnglishFlashCard.txt";
    private List<string> _lines; //-- The error goes here
    private int _currentLineIndex;

    //private FlashCard _flashCard;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //_lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(path).ToList();

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    _lines.Add(line);
            }
        }

        CurrentLineIndex = 0;
    }

    private void btnLeft_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.CurrentLineIndex--;
    }

    private void btnRight_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.CurrentLineIndex++;
    }

    private void UpdateContentLabel()
    {
        this.FlashText.Text = _lines[CurrentLineIndex];
    }

    private int CurrentLineIndex
    {
        get {  return _currentLineIndex; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0 || value >= _lines.Count) return;
            _currentLineIndex = value;
            UpdateContentLabel();
        }
    }
}
```

I've got the error on the line marked above said: **Field 'FCard.MainPage._lines' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null**.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: If you post your code we can help you more.

Comment: If you edit your question with it it'd be easier to read.

Comment: The argument out of range exceptions are happening because your file is not being loaded in the LoadCard (because of the first error you're getting). Now the problem is why are you getting that first error. This is a windows phone 7 application by the looks of it. I wonder if you can't just access the file in the normal way. I don't know much about WP7 apps, but a google search for you error brings back discussions of `IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()`. If this is a windows phone 7 application, perhaps add the tag to your question. You'll probably attract an avid WP7 developer.

Comment: @Jason: Ok. better I will try to post a new thread and change the title :)
Thanks for your kind reply, Jason! It's help me a lot :)

Comment: Just a note on your Update 2 above... You are getting the compiler warning because you have the line commented out that actually instantiates the _lines variable. Remember that just saying `private List<string> _lines;` is not instantiating the object. You need to set the _lines reference to something (either via `_lines = new List<string>();` or calling a method that returns a collection of strings, such as the line you have commented out).

Comment: @Jason: I do. The code become like: `private List<string> _lines = new List<string>();`, but while I debug it, there is no error but nothing happen to the emulator, it's just appear a small clock.

Comment: @Jason: I've add an instantiating on the constructor, it's `_lines = new List<string>();` after the `InitializeComponent();`, but it's do nothing, just the same.

Comment: It still sounds like some kind of issue with the file access. I wonder if the emulator is causing issues when you try to open the file and populate the list. Maybe it's hanging on ReadAllLines... bah, I don't know.

Comment: @Jason: Haha.. It's make me going crazy being stuck on the same problem several times. Btw thanks for your help, it's help me a lot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be able to read lines moving backward and forward within the file you'll either need to store all of the lines inside of an object (perhaps a `List<string>` or string array), or you'll have to manually reposition your cursor via a `Seek` method (such as [FileStream.Seek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek.aspx)). It will depend on how big the flash card file is. If it's very large (contains many lines), you may not want to store it all in memory, preferring instead the seek option.

Here is a sample loading the entire contents of the flash card:

```
namespace FlashReader
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Hold your flash card lines in here
        private List<string> _lines;

        // Track your current line
        private int _currentLine;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Load up your file
            LoadFile(@"D:\Path\To\EnglishFlashCard.txt");
        }
```

Your load file could look something like this:

```
        private void LoadFile(string file)
        {
            using (var reader = File.OpenText(file))
            {
                _lines = new List<string>();

                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    _lines.Add(line);
                }
            }

            // Set this to -1 so your first push of next sets the current
            // line to 0 (first element in the array)
            _currentLine = -1;
        }
```

Your previous click could look like this:

```
        private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayPrevious();
        }

        private void DisplayPrevious()
        {
            // Already at first line
            if (_currentLine == 0) return;

            _currentLine--;

            FlashText.Text = _lines[_currentLine];
        }
```

Your next button click could look like this:

```
        private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayNext();
        }

        private void DisplayNext()
        {
            // Already at last line
            if (_currentLine == _lines.Count - 1) return;

            _currentLine++;

            FlashText.Text = _lines[_currentLine];
        }
    }
}
```

You would want to add some error checking of course (what if the file is missing etc.).

PS - I've compiled this code using a file with the following lines and confirmed that it works:

```
Line one 
Line two 
Line three 
Line four
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to go with something more akin to an object-oriented approach, consider creating a FlashCard class. Something like this:

```
public class FlashCard
{
    private readonly string _file;
    private readonly List<string> _lines;

    private int _currentLine;

    public FlashCard(string file)
    {
        _file = file;
        _currentLine = -1;

        // Ensure the list is initialized
        _lines = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            LoadCard();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // either handle or throw some meaningful message that the card
            // could not be loaded.
        }
    }

    private void LoadCard()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(_file))
        {
            // Throw a file not found exception
        }

        using (var reader = File.OpenText(_file))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                _lines.Add(line);
            }
        }
    }

    public string GetPreviousLine()
    {
        // Make sure we're not at the first line already
        if (_currentLine > 0)
        {
            _currentLine--;
        }

        return _lines[_currentLine];
    }

    public string GetNextLine()
    {
        // Make sure we're not at the last line already
        if (_currentLine < _lines.Count - 1)
        {
            _currentLine++;
        }

        return _lines[_currentLine];
    }
}
```

Now you can instead do something like this in your main form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private FlashCard _flashCard;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This could go under somewhere like a load new flash card button or
        // menu option etc.
        try
        {
            _flashCard = new FlashCard(@"c:\temp\EnglishFlashCard.txt");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
           // do something
        }
    }

    private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayPrevious();
    }

    private void DisplayPrevious()
    {
        FlashText.Text = _flashCard.GetPreviousLine();
    }


    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayNext();
    }

    private void DisplayNext()
    {
        FlashText.Text = _flashCard.GetNextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jason, wow thanks for the code :) 
But I've got this error while trying to compiling the solution: 

  `'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' could be found. `

It got the blue error line under the 'Length' on if (_currentLine == _lines.Length - 1) return; on DisplayNext() 

  fyi, I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone and .Net 4.0 Framework.

Comment: Thanks @Jason, really appreciated it :) . But now I've got the 

  `'NullReferenceException was unhandled'` error for the `"if (_currentLine == _lines.Count - 1)"` line while trying to compiling the solution. I've try to remove these line, but I've got the `"FlashText.Text = _lines[_currentLine];"` error with the same message.

Comment: @mrjimoy_05: I made some last minute changes, but was rushed, so I never double checked that everything still compiled. I'll check it out now and make any necessary edits.

Comment: @mrjimoy_05: It compiles and runs fine for me. Make sure your `_lines` (`List<string>`) has been initialized. It gets initialized in the `LoadFile(string file)` method (`_lines = new List<string>();`), so make sure that is called before you try to move to the next or previous line the first time. Are you calling load file (and ensuring it is actually there) in the Form Load event (or wherever makes sense for your application)?

Comment: @mrjimoy_05: I created a "better" example for you in the UPDATE section of my answer. You'd be better off separating the FlashCard logic from the form.

Comment: I've tried the latest solution provided, it made some error because it doesn't provide the complete 'using directive', so I've tried to add the   `"using System.Collections.Generic;"` and   `"using System.Linq;"` to the class. It's reduce the error but it's still generate an error under the 'File' code, it's "The name 'File' does not exist in the current context.". So I want to make sure the 'using directive' you've added to the solution and please let me know :) Thanks

Comment: @mrjimoy_05: You need to add `using System.IO;`

Comment: I've added it and the solution could run. But again, while I'm hitting the 'Next' button, it's get error for the   `"FlashText.Text = _flashCard.GetNextLine();"` line said   `NullReferenceException was unhandled`, and so for   `"FlashText.Text = _flashCard.GetPreviousLine();"` line while hitting the 'Previous' button. omg I am going crazy of this... Anyway thanks for the help, Jason! I will try to solve it :)

Comment: Wmrjimoy_05: I don't know... you'd have to post what you have. It should work. I'd step through it with a debbugger to track down the issue. I'm guessing either you are not creating the _flashCard before trying to use it (or it is failing on the creation because an exception is being thrown during the creation (maybe you're catching it, but still continuing on)), or maybe the FlashText control itself is not being created. Without seeing exactly what you've got, it's all speculation.

Comment: I do initiating the _flashCard, just like what you've show above (private FlashCard _flashCard;) --> right?

Comment: That's defining it, but it's not instantiated until you actually call `_flashCard = new FlashCard("path-to-your-file");`. You also need to make sure that it does not fail creating it (is the correct file being passed in... is it opening the file and reading in the contents without throwing an exception?).

Comment: I called it. But I do not adding any code on the  `//do something` section. You means this part?

Comment: @mrjimoy_05: If you are catching an exception, but not actually putting code in there to do anything, you're basically eating it. This can cause problems later. I'm guessing that you are not able to load the file (if you copied my example exactly, it's looking for file `c:\temp\EnglishFlashCard.txt`. Make sure you have changed the path to the proper location. Also, fill in the error handling however it makes sense. Even if you change it to `catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }` And set a break point at the constructor of the FlashCard, so you can step through in debug mode.

Comment: I've found the problem. The solution doesn't loading the Form1_Load, so I put it on the constructor. But I've got the new error message while hitting the 'Next' / 'Previous' button. It's get  `return _lines[_currentLine];` error and said:  `"ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled"`. I've tried to put a 'try catch' to the:
  `try { FlashText.Text = _flashCard.GetNextLine();} catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);}` and while clicking the 'Next' / 'Previous' button, it got message: `'Parameter name: index'`.

Comment: @mrjimoy_05: That means that even though you managed to create the FlashCard object, it still didn't load any lines. You could ensure that there is actually data in your _lines before attempting to access it (check for `if (_lines.Count == 0)` and if so, inform the user that the flash card is empty or did not load properly... make sure you call `return;` before hitting the `_lines[_currentLine];` or you'll still have the exception. Ideally, you should post an update to your question, typing in what you have now. As I said, I can only guess what your problem is without seeing what you have.

Answer (score 2):

You might separate the parsing phase from the displaying phase.
First, read each row of your file and make a list of string of it:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath); 
while(!file.EndOfStream)
{ 
  string line = file.ReadLine();
  list.Add(line);
} 
Console.WriteLine("{0} lines read", list.Count);
FlashText.Text = list[0];
```

Then, keep an id of the current item and display it in your block.

```
private int curId = 0;

// on next button click
if (curId < list.Count - 1)
  FlashText.Text = list[++curId];

// on prev button click
if (curId > 0)
  FlashText.Text = list[--curId];
```

Comment: Hi Gracchus, thanks for the code.
I'll give it a try and tell you soon. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I've been reading stack overflow for a long time, now it's my turn to share :)

Comment: :) I've a little bit confused about placing the code on the solution. Your first part of code is placed under the public Form1() (if it is named Form1), and the next button click part is under the next button event handler and so for the prev button click? And place the 'private int curId = 0; inside the partial class? But it doesn't work. I've got this error under the 'add' code: 

  `'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'add' and no extension method 'add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' could be found.`

Comment: fyi, I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 for Windows Phone and .Net 4.0 Framework.

Comment: Sorry, it's "Add" actually. When you have a "...does not contains definition.." error in VS, try to Ctrl-Space it to to display the intellisense completion. It's an actual trick many of my student still don't understand ! And you're right for the location of each of my snippets.

Comment: Thanks, the solution could run but the emulator just only showing a clock there, and after waiting for several minutes, there is no change. I am going crazy of this. Anyway, thanks for the help, Gracchus. I will try to solve it :)

Answer (score 1):

I like the existing answers, but I think creating a class to represent a list of objects is overkill for this problem. I'd prefer to keep it simple - a list of string should just be represented by `List<string>`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string path = @"D:\temp\test.txt";
    private List<string> _lines;
    private int _currentLineIndex;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // if you're adding these using a reader then 
        // you need to initialize the List first...
        _lines = new List<string>();

        _lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
        CurrentLineIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Three simple methods - one to handle the Back click, one to handle the Forward click, and one to update the label.

```
    private void BackButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.CurrentLineIndex--;
    }

    private void ForwardButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.CurrentLineIndex++;
    }

    private void UpdateContentLabel()
    {
        this.ContentLabel.Text = _lines[CurrentLineIndex];
    }
```

And when the CurrentLineIndex property is set, trigger the `UpdateContentLabel()`

```
    private int CurrentLineIndex
    {
        get {  return _currentLineIndex; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0 || value >= _lines.Count) return;
            _currentLineIndex = value;
            UpdateContentLabel();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I've found error while putting the `'ReadAllLines'` code said: `'System.IO.File' does not contain a definition for 'ReadLines'`, so I've changed the lines (please take a look on the 'UPDATE 2' above). But I've got error message for the `private List<string> _lines;`, said: `Field 'FCard.MainPage._lines' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null`

Comment: You need to initialise: `_lines = new List<string>();`

Comment: Okay. But I am using .NET 4 Framework and Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone.

Comment: Yes. But I've got nothing while running it, just a small clock appear on the emulator, and there is an error under the `'private List<string> _lines;'` line. While I try to add the code become: `private List<string> _lines = new List<string>();`, there is no error, but the emulator just showed a small clock.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you where to initialize the List.

Comment: Put some breakpoints in the code - or write to debug - & press the buttons to determine that the correct line is being retrieved from the ContentLabel. Using WindowsPhone is different to WinForms, I believe you need to use a MVVM type pattern. That's another whole question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try to use that way. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this function. It works for me, hope it helps you too

```
    private string ReadFile(string filePath)
    {
        //this verse is loaded for the first time so fill it from the text file
        var ResrouceStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(filePath, UriKind.Relative));
        if (ResrouceStream != null)
        {
            Stream myFileStream = ResrouceStream.Stream;
            if (myFileStream.CanRead)
            {
                StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(myFileStream);

                //read the content here
                return myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        return "NULL";
    }
```

Then use split function to split it on `\n\r`. In that way you will get the lines of the file. Store them in an array or list. Then call for the respective index on next or previous. Check for `NULL` before proceeding.

Comment: You are welcome. If it helped you in your task, please accept/upvote as you feel appropriate :)